# How to add new raster store and publish for ECW fromat in GeoServer 2.4-RC2?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, raster, gdal, ecw

I am using GeoServer 2.4 RC2 and Tomcat7 on windows xp OS. I have extracted the gdal-data.zip (2.4.0) and geoserver-2.4-SNAPSHOT-gdal-plugin into Tomcat 7.0\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib. Now Geoserver shows ECW in raster data source list.

[image]

Then I did the following;

[image]

My ECW file path is G:\ECW\DB010_7500.ECW.

[image]

I gave Data Source Name as ECW (folder name). Then I clicked the save button but nothing happened. I navigated to Layers->Add a new resource, I can see site: ECW in dropdown list. But there is no effect when I select it from dropdown list.

[image]

So I am not able to publish it. I don't know these steps are right way to publish ECW image on Geoserver. Please suggest me to do this.

Comment: I've had the same issue arise. I haven't been able to get ECW working on GeoServer 2.4.